# serial port ttyUSB0 read block when use libev

Tags: c, linux, libev

I have a serial port ttyUSB0, and open it with NONBLOCK.

`fd = open(args_info.dev_arg, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);`

use `read` will immediate return, everything is ok. But when use libev

`ev_io_init(&serial->recv_ctx->io, serial_recv_cb, fd, EV_READ);`

`serial_recv_cb` will block until 100bytes. if data length less than 100bytes, `serial_recv_cb` will never be called.

```
[root@jane client]# ./tcptrans --dev /dev/ttyUSB0 -d 7 --nic wlp2s0
serial.c +163 serial_recv_cb(): DEBUG: fd: 5, size: 100
serial.c +163 serial_recv_cb(): DEBUG: fd: 5, size: 100
```

I think `serial_recv_cb` will be called immediate. Why libev will block ?

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: Why libev do not call serial_recv_cb immediate?

Comment: It shouldn't do any callbacks until you call ev_run.

Comment: What [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) settings do you set for the serial port?

Answer (score 0):

`termios` have `VMIN` and `VTIME`.My VMIN set 100 and VTIME is 0. so will wait until 100bytes.